# How to get page id of a facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch page id of a facebook page of a given URL in graph API.
e.g this is the URL http://www.facebook.com/platform and I want to get the page id of this facebook page.
I tried all the possible solution but failed. Please any one help me....Please...
Thanx!

Comment: You can follow the details steps as explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329303/12326605 to get the Page access token and Page id.

Answer (score 11):

Just look in the source code of the fb page and search for page_id.
Voila!

Comment: It's a little different now - here is what I found now works: "profile_delegate_page_id":"102248448806892"

Comment: And the corresponding URL for iPhone is now like fb://page?id=102248448806892 - note this does NOT work on Android or web!

Answer (score 9):

The answers given before Oct 27, 2015 no longer work, and the other answer given after that is not dynamic, but requires site scraping. This answer provides the necessary `URLs`.

1) Get your App-id and App-secret by choosing an existing app or creating a new one at this url:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

2) Get an access token by making a GET request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + APP_ID + "&client_secret=" + APP_SECRET + "&grant_type=client_credentials
```

3) To get the page-id of your fan page, you need the page-name. Go to your fan page on facebook and look at the url. It will have this form:

```
https://www.facebook.com/{fan-page-name}
```

Once you have that, make a GET request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{fan-page-name}?access_token={access-token}
```

It will return a bunch of JSON. You're looking for the first "id" element. This is your page-id.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660728/embed-activity-feed-of-a-public-facebook-page-without-forcing-user-to-login-allo/26722934#26722934).

Answer (score 8):

On the page, Press for code source: "Ctrl+U"
and search "page_id", on the second or third search, you will find a 16 digit page id.

Now open copy the link: `facebook.com/<your-page-id>` to verify your finding.

Comment: In my case the ID was 11 numeric digits. It's NOT the alphanumeric one that starts with `Prod...`.

Answer (score 7):

The answers given before this one (Oct 27, 2015) no longer work.

What works right now is to go to the page or user's Facebook page, and grep the source for `fb://page/\d+` or `fb://profile/\d+`.

Example:

https://www.facebook.com/idorecall/

contains

> fb://page/1605841049661522

https://www.facebook.com/dandasco

contains

> fb://profile/100002764094643

Try this on the command line:

```
curl -skA "Mozilla/5.0" https://www.facebook.com/idorecall/ | grep -oE "fb://[^\"]+"
```

Comment: Either I'm making the wrong call, `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed`, or your approach isn't actually working. I'm also worried about its dependability. All I need is a public page's news feed, but I keep getting `Invalid OAuth access token` error.

Comment: @craned: You might have been overthinking it. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to site scrape. Not only that, but Java doesn't make it easy to do so. I posted a more dynamic answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's ridiculous how complicated it is to fetch a URL or read a line from a file in Java, compared to, say, Perl.

Answer (score 6):

**Only solution what worked for me.**

Paste desired facebook URL in input

[image]

field and it will print Page ID.

[image]

https://www.duplichecker.com/find-facebook-id.php

hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Just use https://graph.facebook.com/your_username and after you can see all the detain and your ID

Comment: This no longer works. I get OAuth exceptions for both usernames and pages.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, what do you do now? I'm trying to find a fix for an app.

Answer (score 2):

Just Go To https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
Type in the name of your page in the box and click submit and you will get your page id

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 $url="http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola";
    $content=file_get_contents($url);
    $x=json_decode($content);
    echo $x->id;
```

Comment: This no longer works. I get OAuth exceptions for both usernames and pages.

Comment: please check answer date

Comment: I have. That's why I said that it "*no longer* works". It's unfortunate, but one must resort to other methods.

Comment: ok, then post it as answer dude, its old answer and I'm unable to delete it